# Python re-ordering a list of tuples by pre-defined sequence

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

I have a list of tuples that I want to sort by a specific order which has been pre-defined:

```
Tuple_list=[(0, 1), (0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 0), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2)]

order=[5,7,4,1,6,2,3]

sorted_tuples=[(2,3), (3,2), (2,0), (0,1), (3,1), (0,3), (1,3)]
```

The order refers to the position of the tuple in the list. I've been trying to use python's sorted function, but can't get it to produce the desired output, and can't find a thread to help with this particular type of tuple sorting problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [Tuple_list[i-1] for i in order]
[(2, 3), (3, 2), (2, 0), (0, 1), (3, 1), (0, 3), (1, 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This "sort" is called a permutation

```
sorted_tuples = map(lambda o: Tuple_list[o-1], order)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a sorting algorithm if you already know what elements to take in what order -- just iterate over the indices instead and get the corresponding list items:

```
sorted_tuples = [tuple_list[i - 1] for i in order]
```

or, if you use real zero-based Python indices instead

```
sorted_tuples = operator.itemgetter(*order)(tuple_list)
```